Enterprise application doesn't start in OpenLiberty
Trying to deploy IBM's sample application libertyDefaultApplicationCLIENT-CERT.ear ( from this article: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-setup-liberty-use-certificate-based-authentication )
My server.xml is
<server description="Sample Liberty server">

  <featureManager>
    <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
    <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>
... 
  <variable name="http.port" defaultValue="9080"/>
  <variable name="https.port" defaultValue="9443"/>

  <httpEndpoint httpPort="${http.port}" httpsPort="${https.port}"
      id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="*" />
      
  <enterpriseApplication location="libertyDefaultApplicationCLIENT-CERT.ear" contextRoot="/test" />
</server>


The file is in config/apps directory. When I  start the server theer are entries in log file related to the aplication start up.
And  when  I try https://localhost:9443/test I get HTTP 404 error:
Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /test

However from AdminCenter tells me libertyDefaultApplicationCLIENT-CERT  is running on defaultServer
If it is running - how can I access it

You dont have any "application" related feature enabled. For a start, it looks like quite old app so I'd try with <feature>javaee-8.0</feature> . Of course this is a bundle, and you may find it better to be more granular and add just jsp, ejb etc. Depends on your needs and app.

Thanks @Gas
That got application deployed - kind of. It ignored contextRoot  arttribute and deplyed it at the root - i.e. "https://localhost:9443/snoop" worked, not "https://localhost:9443/test/snoop" as I would have expected.  It also did not served the purpose it was designed for - I expected it to respond with HTTP403 ( as it supouse to illustrate client-cert authentication )  , and it did on the first request but then let me in on reload.
But all this are the subjects for the new post.

Most probably your browser "auto selects" matching certificate, so you have to ensure that it is disabled to have prompt each time, and usually once authenticated it will be used for the whole session (otherwise it would be a nightmare to select cert after each page reload :-) )

There are several issues. That article is quite old and has some gaps.

You dont need <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature> as this is only for "console management"
You need <feature>javaee-8.0</feature> to enable application runtime features as written in the comment
To enforce security in the application you of course need <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
This is "bundeled" EAR app, so it has web module included in the ear, with the root context defined there (application.xml file). You could override that in configuration, see docs here - https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/enterpriseApplication.html and this post How can I set the context root in Liberty using server configuration (server.xml) for my EAR-packaged WARs?

